# UISearchBar not displaying correctly in UTableViewHeader

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

Added a uisearch bar and uisearchbardisplaycontoller programatically (NO XIB) and the search bar sorta displays in the table header but is non functional.

if setActive:YES, setActive:NO on the display controller it appears just fine and is functional

Any ideas why this might be happening?

THanks in advance

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[self setSearchBarDisplayController:[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self]];
[[self searchBarDisplayController] setDelegate:self];
[[self searchBarDisplayController] setSearchResultsDataSource:self];

summaryTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 416.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease]; 
[summaryTableView setDataSource:self];
[summaryTableView setDelegate:self];
[summaryTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[summaryTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
[summaryTableView setRowHeight:[PayCell height]];

[summaryTableView setTableHeaderView:searchBar];

[self.view addSubview:summaryTableView];

[searchBarDisplayController setActive:YES];
[searchBarDisplayController setActive:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you haven't set up the searchResultsDelegate for the search display controller?

```
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

On the [Developer Site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference is made to this. Without seeing more code, it's hard to say, but not setting it could be the root of your problem. Here's an excerpt:

> searchResultsDelegate The delegate for
>   the table view in which the search
>   results are displayed.
>
> @property(nonatomic, assign)
>   id
>   searchResultsDelegate Discussion The
>   default is nil.

Comment: Thanks, But setting the searchResultsDelegate didn't do anything.  The code is really simple... a view with UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate that creates a searchBarDisplayController, searchbar and a  uitable.   all the delegate methods for the table view are implemented and load the table with a single row.   search delegates are implemented but empty just return default values. At this point I'm just trying to get the searhbar to appear correctly with having to call setActive:YES setActive:NO on the searchBarDisplayController.